# This is giving me typecasting issue. How to store 001 in arg

Tags: c, strstr

```
char *arg;
arg = strstr(buff, 001);
```

This is giving me typecasting problem. How to store 001 in arg?

Comment: What programming language is that? C? Please tag your question to include the programming language.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Yes, it's C

Comment: @DonaldDuck I want to search 001 from buff and store into arg

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm

Comment: Do you mean `001` (an octal constant of type `int`, exactly equivalent to the decimal constant `1`), or `"001"`, a string literal?

Answer (score 2):

> This is giving me typecasting problem. How to store 001 in arg?

The second argument of the C function `strstr` must be of type `const char *`. You are instead passing an `int`. Use quotes.

`arg = strstr(buff, "001");`

Comment: The *parameter* is of type `const char*`. The *argument* can be `const char*` or `char*`. In this case it's of type `char*` (because C string literals, unlike C++ string literals, are not `const`). (`"001"` is actually of type `char[4]`, but it's implicitly converted at compile time to `char*`.)

Comment: Thank you @KeithThompson for additional detail. Appreciate your feedback.